# What are "month", "week", and "day" in my new dashboard?

Tags: support, profile-page

What do **month**, **week**, and **day** in my new dashboard resemble?

I had seen other profiles; it was distinct from every profile.

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

An extremely wild guess:

[image: Votes cast this month/week/day]

**Edit:** Read it as: `Votes Cast ... this ... month/week/day`. And if you don't know what a vote is...eeerrrr...[here's the FAQ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq).

Answer (score 5):

**month** is the number of votes cast since the beginning of the month.
**week** is the number of votes cast since the beginning of the week.
**day** is the number of votes cast since the beginning of the day.

While the beginning of the day is always the most recent event (meaning that the votes count for day will always be the lowest), note that there are situations where a week overlaps two months. For instance, today, Friday February 1st, here is my display:

[image]

The **month** currently only covers Feb 1, the **week** covers Jan 28-Feb 1, and the **day** covers Feb 1.